# I get an error wen I try to change the name of a *.db file

Tags: python, file, rename

I'm trying to change the name of a *.db file, so I store the file path in a variable, then I change the the name of the file with the name that the user gives using a GUI. But when I try to rename the file using the os.rename() method I got an error.

At first, I had this prosses within a "whith open(*file path*) as f:" statement, but when I realized that the opened file was the file I was trying to change I got it out. I also tyed to make a copy of the original directory and then using the copy to declare the new file path (even knowing it was changeing of id adress).

Although all my efforts I still get the followin error:
    [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:'C:\Users\Aitor Cantero Crespo\Desktop\GUI_py\soso.db' -> 'C:\Users\Aitor Cantero Crespo\Desktop\GUI_py\sos.db'

Here is the code:

```
def Modificar(NombreDelProyecto, NombreDelCliente, Descripcion, LetraRevision, FechaRevision, LetraFuerza, LetraMedida,     #|
                                            LetraControl, LetraComunicacion, MargenEnOrigen, MargenEnDestino):          #|- Variables de la función
    global Directorio


    Info =  [NombreDelProyecto, NombreDelCliente, Descripcion, LetraRevision, FechaRevision,                            #|
                        LetraFuerza, LetraMedida, LetraControl, LetraComunicacion, MargenEnOrigen, MargenEnDestino]     #|- Datos del proyecto

    Conexion = connect('{}'.format(Directorio))                                                                         # Crea la conexión con la base de datos


    with Conexion:                                                                                                      # Para trabajar con la base de datos

        Seleccion = Conexion.cursor()
        Seleccion.execute("""SELECT NombreDelProyecto FROM InfProy""")
        Nombre = Seleccion.fetchone()[0]

        Seleccion.execute("""UPDATE InfProy SET NombreDelCliente='{}', Descripcion='{}', LetraRevision='{}', FechaRevision='{}', 
                        LetraFuerza='{}', LetraMedida='{}', LetraControl='{}', LetraComunicacion='{}', MargenEnOrigen='{}', MargenEnDestino='{}'""".format(
                        Info[1], Info[2], Info[3], Info[4], Info[5], Info[6], Info[7], Info[8], Info[9], Info[10]))

    if Nombre != Info[0]:
        with Conexion:                                                                                                      # Para trabajar con la base de datos
            Seleccion = Conexion.cursor()
            Seleccion.execute("""UPDATE InfProy SET NombreDelProyecto='{}'""".format(Info[0]))

        print(Directorio)
        print(Nombre)
        print(Info[0])

        Directorio_N = Directorio.replace(str(Nombre), str(Info[0]))
        Directorio_N = path.normpath(Directorio_N)
        Directorio = path.normpath(Directorio)

        print(Directorio_N)

        rename(Directorio, Directorio_N)
```

I wouldn't expect any error, since I'm only changeing a str and saveing it in a different variable. I can not understand why that prosses is still going on.

Comment: Is indentation correct? May it be the case that you use `with Conexion` inside another `with Conexion`?

Comment: Try physically closing the db file before renaming it.

Comment: Thank you for answering @Poolka, but identation is ok.

Comment: Aitor, think about it:  what happens when you say `Conexion = connect('{}'.format(Directorio))`?  A process is started and Python communicates with this process to alter the database.  Now look at the error message: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process` and ask yourself, which process is accessing the database file?

Comment: Thank you @gboffi that solved the problem

Comment: OK but now please [edit] your question. The body of the function **IS NOT INDENTED** with respect to the initial `def`